# Struct containing reference to a file in Rust fails to borrow

Tags: rust

Not sure what I am missing here, the lifetime is declared, therefore the struct should use the path to create the file and return a Struct with the mutable File reference for me to be able to call "write" wrapper later...

```
use std::path::Path;
use std::fs::File;
// use std::io::Write;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Foo<'a> {
    file: &'a mut File,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    pub fn new(path: &'a Path) -> Result<Self, std::io::Error> {
        let mut f: &'a File = &File::create(path)?;

        Ok(Self { file: &mut f })
    }

    //pub fn write(&self, b: [u8]) {
    //    self.file.write(b);
    //}
}
```

Error:

```
   | impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
11 |     pub fn new(path: &'a Path) -> Result<Self, std::io::Error> {
12 |         let mut f: &'a File = &File::create(path)?;
   |                    --------    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
   |                    |
   |                    type annotation requires that borrow lasts for `'a`
...
15 |     }
   |     - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
```

Comment: I would recommend reading the ["Understanding Ownership" chapter of _The Rust Programming Language_](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) if you haven't yet. A reference to a function's local value could never outlive that lifetime `'a`, defined by the caller.

Comment: Being more objective, is there a way that I can have a reference to a File inside of a struct other than manually creating it? (the function `new` is trying to create the file and returning a struct where the file reference is given for future use). In order to avoid doing: `CommitLog { file: File.create... }`

Comment: This raises the question: why do you want to keep only a reference? It seems to me that you would prefer `Foo` _owning_ the file rather than borrowing it. (And please [edit] the question to include all the details)

Answer (score 0):

As @E_net4 mentioned, I don't want a mutable reference, yet I want to own the value. Rather than trying to play with lifetimes, I can basically just own the file and handle the whole struct as mutable when trying to write to the file!

```
use std::path::{ PathBuf };
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;
use std::env;


#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Foo {
    file:  File,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn new(path: PathBuf) -> Self {
        Self { 
          file: File::create(path).unwrap(),
        }
    }

    pub fn write(&mut self, b: &[u8]) -> Result<usize, std::io::Error> {
        self.file.write(b)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut tmp_dir = env::temp_dir();
    tmp_dir.push("foo23");
    let mut f = Foo::new(tmp_dir);

    f.write(b"test2").unwrap();
}
```